# PassportJS gives me the tokens but returns a 401 Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm writing a webserver for a desktop application that access the Google API v3 and for that I need to use their oAuth 2.0.

The webserver uses PassportJS with the `passport-google-oauth20` strategy and it works because I receive the access token and refresh token.

I don't intend to keep the user data, nor do I need cookies for the desktop app. All I really need is an accessToken and the refreshToken so that the user doesn't need to log-in every time.

So far so good, but after Google sends the tokens, it somehow fails? I'm pretty sure it isn't Google who's sending a 401 but the way I set it up.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641701/passportjs-authenticates-user-but-returns-401-unauthorized-on-subsequent-request) but this doesn't work for me since I need the tokens.

Here is the strategy setup:

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/oauth/callback"
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, _, done) => {
      console.log("access token: ", accessToken);
      console.log("refresh token: ", refreshToken);
      done(null, null)
    }
  )
);
```

and here is the relevant part of the server

```js
server.get("/authorized", (req, res) => res.send("Login Succeeded"));
server.get("/fail", (req, res) => res.send("Login Failed"));

server.get(
  "/oauth",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "email"],
    accessType: "offline",
    approvalPrompt: "force",
  })
);

server.get(
  "/oauth/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "/authorized",
    failureRedirect: "/fail",
    failureFlash: true,
    failWithError: true,
  })
);
```

and if you want to see it for yourself, [here is a snippet repo](https://github.com/RodPaDev/webserver-oauth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your strategy callback you need to supply Passport with the user that authenticated or it will consider it a failed authentication attempt.

I was able to get your code to work and redirect to the `authorized` route by updating `done()` to the following:

```js
    (accessToken, refreshToken, _, done) => {
      console.log("access token: ", accessToken);
      console.log("refresh token: ", refreshToken);
      done(null, _)
    }
```